# why does "read_hdf " in pandas not working?

Tags: python, pandas

when I run the following code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
nsfg = pd.read_hdf('nsfg.hdf5','nsfg')
type(nsfg)
nsfg.head()
```

I get the this error:

```
File "c:\Users\pro\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\main folder\data science\python for data analysis\pandas.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "c:\Users\pro\OneDrive\سطح المكتب\main folder\data science\python for data analysis\pandas.py", line 2, in <module>
    nsfg = pd.read_hdf('nsfg.hdf5','nsfg')
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_hdf' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Comment: AttributeError: partially initialized module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_hdf' (most likely due to a circular import)

Comment: You named your file `pandas.py`, rename it to something different.